# Proving that sum of two form is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

let $f_r$ an homogenous form of degree $r$ and $f_{r+1}$  a form of degree $r-1$ without commun factors, in $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$.
 I want to show that the sum $f = f_r + f_{r+1}$  is irreducible. (exercise 2.34 from Fulton, Algebraic Curves.)

I tried to homogenize the polynomial and I get $f^* = x_{n+1}f_r + f_{r+1}$. I know that $f$ factors $\Leftrightarrow$ $f^*$ does (except for factorisation of $f^*$ by the power of $x_{n+1}$).

But I have no more information with this. Can I get some hints ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If $f=gh$, with $ord(g),ord(h)>0$ then $ord(g)+ord(h)=r-1$ and $deg(g)+deg(h)=r$.

We have that $$r-1=ord(g)+ord(h)\leq deg(g)+ord(h)\leq deg(g)+deg(h)=r.$$
 Therefore one of the two inequalities is an equality.
This means that either $g$ or $h$ is homogeneous, and therefore both are homogeneous, together with $f$.

Answer (score 3):

sorry to revive such an old post, but I was looking for an answer to this exercise (thought it would be hard, but turned out to be really easy), and the answer given although it seems to be correct, personally I am not familiar with the ord notation, I can't find it included in the curve book, so anyway, here's a simpler answer which is probably equivalent.

Let $f_r+f_{r+1}=gh$ $g=a_1+a_2+...+a_n$ where the a_i are none 0 forms which satisfy $deg(a_i)>deg(a_{i+1})$, analogously define $h=b_1+...+b_m$. Clearly, we have $deg(a_n)+deg(b_m)=deg(a_1)+deg(b_1)-1$, therefore wlog, $g=a_1$, $h=b_1+b_2$, which implies $f_r=a_1b_2$, $f_{r+1}=a_1b_1$, so either $f_r+f_{r+1}$ is irreducible, or $f_r$ and $f_{r+1}$ share $a_1$ as a common factor.